# Pattern for adding entry and exit trace to a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out the best way of tracing the return value of a method when the method has multiple exit points. I have dozens of methods I want to add tracing to. I'll run through what I have tried.

First I tried refactoring each method to have a single exit point like this:

```
StatusCode CreateResource(string name, string type)
{
    Trace.LogEvent("BEGIN CreateResource name=" + name + " type=" + type);
    StatusCode status = StatusCode.Ok;
    if (!IsValidResourceName(name))
        status = StatusCode.InvalidName;
    else
    {
        if (!IsValidResourceType(type))
            status = StatusCode.InvalidType;
        else
        {
            if (!SystemOnline())
                status = StatusCode.SystemOffline;
            //continues to nest with more conditions
        }
    }
    Trace.LogEvent("END CreateResource result=" + status);
    return status;
}
```

But the nested if statements make it ugly and less readable. I have made heavy use of early exit points as [guard statements](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) and refactoring it all just creates a mess, feels like de-refactoring.

Another thing I tried was to wrap each method in another method that traces the return value:

```
StatusCode CreateResource(string name, string type)
{
    Trace.LogEvent("BEGIN CreateResource name=" + name + " type=" + type);
    StatusCode status = CreateResource_DONT_CALL_THIS_METHOD(name, type);
    Trace.LogEvent("END CreateResource result=" + status);
    return status;
}

StatusCode CreateResource_DONT_CALL_THIS_METHOD(string name, string type)
{
    if (!IsValidResourceName(name))
        return StatusCode.InvalidName;
    if (!IsValidResourceType(type))
        return StatusCode.InvalidType;
    if (!SystemOnline())
        return StatusCode.SystemOffline;
    return StatusCode.Ok;
}
```

The problem is how to prevent in future other developers (or me) calling the wrapped method and bypassing the tracing, hence that ridiculous (and contradicting) name of the wrapped method. I could define and call an anonymous method for the internal method, but that's quite a messy pattern to use throughout the project.

The most solid and readable method I found was this, it's sort of OK IMO but I have doubts this use of a for statement is going to fly in a code review:

```
StatusCode CreateResource_Internal(string name, string type)
{
    Trace.LogEvent("BEGIN CreateResource name=" + name + " type=" + type);
    StatusCode status = StatusCode.Ok;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (!IsValidResourceName(name))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidName;
            break;
        }
        if (!IsValidResourceType(type))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidType;
            break;
        }
        if (!SystemOnline())
        {
            status = StatusCode.SystemOffline;
            break;
        }
    }
    Trace.LogEvent("END CreateResource result=" + status);
    return status;
}
```

I tried a variation using a try finally block:

```
StatusCode CreateResource_Internal(string name, string type)
{
    Trace.LogEvent("BEGIN CreateResource name=" + name + " type=" + type);
    StatusCode status = StatusCode.Ok;
    try
    {
        if (!IsValidResourceName(name))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidName;
            return status;
        }
        if (!IsValidResourceType(type))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidType;
            return status;
        }
        if (!SystemOnline())
        {
            status = StatusCode.SystemOffline;
            return status;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Trace.LogEvent("END CreateResource result=" + status);
    }
    return StatusCode.Ok;
}
```

The downside here is that it's possible to forget to set the 'status' variable before returning in which case tracing will not be performed.

My question is, is there a best practice for doing this? Am I expected to refactor to a single exit point? Is there some way of preventing a wrapped method from being called from elsewhere? Is the danger of allowing tracing to be bypassed worse than the untidiness of refactoring to single exit point?

p.s I don't want to bring in something heavy like aspect oriented programming.

Comment: Did any of the suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used the `try-finally` scheme, but with the entire method wrapped in the `try`-block.

Something like this:

```
StatusCode CreateResource_Internal(string name, string type)
{
    try
    {
        Trace.LogEvent("BEGIN CreateResource name=" + name + " type=" + type);
        StatusCode status = StatusCode.Ok;

        if (!IsValidResourceName(name))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidName;
            return status;
        }
        if (!IsValidResourceType(type))
        {
            status = StatusCode.InvalidType;
            return status;
        }
        if (!SystemOnline())
        {
            status = StatusCode.SystemOffline;
            return status;
        }
        status = StatusCode.Ok; // A bit silly, but that avoids the problem of status not being set.
        return status;
    }
    finally
    {
        Trace.LogEvent("END CreateResource result=" + status);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am balancing simplicity with "correctness" so have accepted this answer for it's simplicity, even though other answers are more "correct" (especially "use AOP").

Comment: I agree, this approach does have its downsides. I mainly stick to it, because I've inherited a large codebase, and a lot of the log entries are customized, so refactoring the logging will not be an easy task.

Answer (score 4):

As a side answer, you could look at implementing `Log4PostSharp`, you can see a tutorial in the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28407/Log4PostSharp-AOP-and-logging).  It may not directly answer your question, but it will help with your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Writing trace files (or any form of logging for that matter) is a typical example of a [Cross Cutting Concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) and you should really try to avoid this type of code in your methods as it makes them A) less readable and B) duplicates a lot of code.

I know you mentioned in your question that you didn't want to add any AOP style programming to your application but I'd really recommend implementing Microsoft Unity for this. It supports [Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) which is exactly the scenario that you're trying to solve here. As long as you follow good programming practice of [coding to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) you'd be surprised how easy it is to implement (and do some pretty cool stuff!).

Just some food for thought...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use dependency injection - if each class implements an interface then the Decorator pattern is the best solution (just a code sketch):

```
interface A
{
  int method1(float x);
}

class AImpl : A
{
    public int method1(float x) { }
}

class LoggedAImpl : A
{
private AImpl innerA;

public int method1(float x) 
{
  //log method and parameters
  int result;
  try
  {
    result = innerA.method1(x);
  }
  finally
  {
    //log method exit
  }
}
}
```

And then, in the application setup:

```
new LoggedAImpl(new AImpl()); //pass it everywhere A is needed
```

Using this with [unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660899%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) seems elegant and relatively painless.

If you don't want to use unity, then at least the Factory pattern along with this above will suffice.